Why is the 6 dropped from the final integral solution?
I was looking at this website to find an integral solution.
But as you can see in the picture the final solution lacks the $6$ that's present above.
Is this an error or the $6$ should really be excluded?


It’s absorbed into $C$; $-6+C=C’$

Some not specified constant $C$ plus constant $-6$ is another not specified constant.

Note the $C$ in both results can have different values either side of $-2$. It's what we call a locally constant function.

If $f(x)+C$ is a valid antiderivative, then so is $f(x)+a+C$. More broadly, you can always "absorb" additive constants into the integration constant because it doesn't actually change the range of possible antideritavies.

@J.G. What do you mean by $-2$?

I think @J.G. means when $x<-2$ vs. when $x>-2$

When you have two constants that are combined in some equation it's common practice in engineering to lump them together into a single constant. You can think of it as $C'=C-6$ but carrying around the $'$ become tedious so it's common to simply make the substitution $C=C-6$ without comment.
